# XQuery for element disregarding parent

Tags: xpath, xquery

I'm new to XQuery and XPath,

I'm trying to query for a certain element type, say a "city". However, this element is listed under various other types of elements, such as "country" and "region". What is a good way to query for all "city" element types regardless of their parent element?

thank you

Comment: nevermind, discovered the '//'

Comment: You should remove the question :)

Comment: It is a good question, no need to remove it. Someone just needs to put the '//' idea in an answer to this question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

- You could write `//city` to find all city elements anywhere in the document.
- You could also use `/descendant-or-self::city`, which is different from the first statement in that it will give you any city elements from the context (starting point where you are executing the statement from).
- If you would like to limit the city elements to all with country as parent, you would write: `//country/city`.
- If you would like to get city elements at a specific depth in a tree, write something like: `/*/*/city`.